# VS code auto import works only on typing and not on quick-fix

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am using Vue-3, and when I am trying to use let's say store like this:

```
const store = useStore();
```

VS code only suggests to import useStore once when I am typing. If I already finished typing and want to import something manually with cmd+. it doesn't show any `import` suggestions. The same happens when I am trying to import my custom types from the sibling folder.

Comment: try `ctrl + space` please

Comment: @ArenHovsepyan sorry, but no luck =/

Comment: @ИванБрагин did you find a solution?

Comment: @Ale unfortunately, no. The problem comes from the bad VS code implementation of Vue IntelliSense. Volar ended up much better than Vetur, but still not perfect. I got used to how PHPStorm detects everything but switched to VS code since I think it Is much better in my case. So my finished result is Volar + TypeScript Plugin Volar(it is a separate package now) + Vue Auto Import(which is not perfect but better than typing all by hand). I think that Vue desperately needs community support in terms of VSCode extensions. Sorry, can't help more here. If I'll find anything, I'll add a comment here.